# Is there any method of accessing a remote filter graph without registering proppage.dll on Windows Vista+?

Tags: c++, com, directshow

I'm currently attempting to developing a small application / dll that will read a remote directshow filter graph and glean information from it for display in a "now playing" style plugin or script. After a few days of reading and subsequent testing, I realized that after getting the filter graph address from the ROT I was failing to convert it from the IUnknown interface pointer to IFilterGraph until I had registered "proppage.dll" which came with Windows SDK.

So what I am asking is, is there no other way to glean any information from a remote filter graph without having to register proppage.dll?

Answer (score 3):

You can't call a COM interface from another address space unless you marshall the interface pointers and parameters/return values to and from the other process. For COM, you need to register a marshalling object for each interface that you want to be able to use cross-process. The standard implementation for that is in proppage.dll.

I don't think there is a simple way to access the interface without providing marshalling. If you don't want to use proppage.dll, you can build marshalling code from the IDL files supplied with the SDK and compile that into your own app.

G